# Why can't this be done? Or can it?

Tags: inequality, optimization

I was writing an answer to [this question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1779625/prove-inequality-8xyz1-for-positive-x-y-z#1779629)

From **AM-HM**
$$\frac1{1+x}+\frac1{1+y}+\frac1{1+z}=2$$
$$\frac{1+x+1+y+1+z}{3}\ge \frac{3}{\frac1{1+x}+\frac1{1+y}+\frac1{1+z}}$$
$$\implies 1+\frac{x+y+z}{3}\ge\frac{3}{2}$$
$$\implies A:= \frac{x+y+z}{3}\ge\frac{1}{2}$$
Now from **AM-GM**
$$ A \ge {(xyz)}^\frac{1}{3} \implies A^3 \ge xyz$$
and $$A^3 \ge \frac1{8}$$
Now from this can we conclude that $\frac1{8}\ge xyz$?

Logically, I can't seem to. Except maybe if we can prove that they achieve the lower bounds simultaneously (since there's an equality in the inequality). Can that be done?

Comment: No you cannot conclude from $P > Q$ and $P > R$ that $Q > R$ or $Q < R$.

Comment: If $a>b$ and $a>c$, then we can't conclude anything about the relationship between $b$ and $c$.

Comment: @Macavity Yes, but its not $>$ here, but $\ge$ which implies the function actually gets to that value, and no less. Can't we conclude from that?

Comment: @Théophile doesn't the $\ge$ (equality) make a difference ?

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: "which implies the function actually gets to that value" - I'm not quite sure you realize what you're saying here.

Comment: Another way you could look at this: why did you conclude that $\frac1{8}\ge xyz$, and not, say, $xyz \ge \frac1{8}$?

Comment: I get your point @TheChaz2.0 My idea was biased. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Could any of you turn that into an answer?